# openwrt wifi udp multicast loss packet and speed limited

Tags: linux, udp, openwrt

I use iperf between two routers for multicast testing.
The first test picture is that the two routers are directly connected to the LAN ports of the two routers with a cable. The multicast test is normal.

```
****192.168.3.1****
root@OpenWrt:~# iperf -c 224.0.0.1 -p 8080 -u -T -t 10 -i 1 -b 20M
iperf: ignoring extra argument -- 10
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 224.0.0.1, UDP port 8080
Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 560.76 us (kalman adjust)
Setting multicast TTL to 0
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.3.1 port 57229 connected with 224.0.0.1 port 8080
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  25.0 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 0 datagrams

****192.168.3.2****
root@OpenWrt:~# iperf -s -u -B 224.0.0.1 -p 8080 -i 1
multicast join failed: No such device
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 8080
Binding to local address 224.0.0.1
Joining multicast group  224.0.0.1
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
multicast join failed: No such device
[  3] local 224.0.0.1 port 8080 connected with 192.168.3.1 port 60332
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.076 ms    0/ 1783 (0%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  2.51 MBytes  21.1 Mbits/sec   0.007 ms    0/ 1790 (0%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.007 ms    0/ 1783 (0%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.005 ms    0/ 1784 (0%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.016 ms    0/ 1783 (0%)
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  20.9 Mbits/sec   0.032 ms    0/ 1780 (0%)
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.076 ms    0/ 1785 (0%)
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.017 ms    0/ 1784 (0%)
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.007 ms    0/ 1784 (0%)
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  25.0 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec   0.028 ms    0/17833 (0%)
```

The second test picture is that the two routers use 2.4g for Mesh Point network connection, point-to-point test, and found that everything is normal (packet loss may be acceptable due to signal interference).

```
****192.168.3.1****
root@OpenWrt:~# iperf -c 192.168.3.2 -u -T -t 100 -i 1 -b 20M
iperf: ignoring extra argument -- 100
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 192.168.3.2, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 560.76 us (kalman adjust)
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.3.1 port 39586 connected with 192.168.3.2 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.27 MBytes  10.7 Mbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  2.37 MBytes  19.9 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.38 MBytes  11.6 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.34 MBytes  19.6 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1.60 MBytes  13.4 Mbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  2.07 MBytes  17.4 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  1.70 MBytes  14.2 Mbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  1.94 MBytes  16.3 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  1.95 MBytes  16.3 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  18.5 MBytes  15.5 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 0 datagrams
[  3] Server Report:
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  18.3 MBytes  15.3 Mbits/sec   1.554 ms  154/13181 (1.2%)

****192.168.3.2****
root@OpenWrt:~# iperf -s -u -B 192.168.3.2 -i 1
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 5001
Binding to local address 192.168.3.2
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.3.2 port 5001 connected with 192.168.3.1 port 39586
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  1.17 MBytes  9.85 Mbits/sec   4.352 ms   25/  863 (2.9%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  2.34 MBytes  19.6 Mbits/sec   0.889 ms    5/ 1671 (0.3%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  1.36 MBytes  11.4 Mbits/sec   1.646 ms   14/  986 (1.4%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.33 MBytes  19.6 Mbits/sec   0.442 ms    5/ 1668 (0.3%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  1.59 MBytes  13.3 Mbits/sec   1.294 ms    8/ 1141 (0.7%)
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  2.09 MBytes  17.5 Mbits/sec   0.941 ms   10/ 1500 (0.67%)
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  1.62 MBytes  13.6 Mbits/sec   2.204 ms   31/ 1186 (2.6%)
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  1.92 MBytes  16.1 Mbits/sec   0.532 ms   32/ 1401 (2.3%)
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  1.95 MBytes  16.4 Mbits/sec   2.025 ms   14/ 1405 (1%)
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  1.81 MBytes  15.2 Mbits/sec   0.534 ms   10/ 1299 (0.77%)
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  18.3 MBytes  15.3 Mbits/sec   1.554 ms  154/13181 (1.2%)
```

The third test picture is that the two routers use 2.4g for Mesh Point networking connection and perform multicast test, and found that the speed is only 50kbye / s and the packet loss rate is very high. Excuse me, what is this question?

```
****192.168.3.1****
root@OpenWrt:~# iperf -c 224.0.0.1 -p 8080 -u -T -t 10 -i 1 -b 20M
iperf: ignoring extra argument -- 10
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 224.0.0.1, UDP port 8080
Sending 1470 byte datagrams, IPG target: 560.76 us (kalman adjust)
Setting multicast TTL to 0
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.3.1 port 59175 connected with 224.0.0.1 port 8080
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  2.50 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  25.0 MBytes  21.0 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 0 datagrams

****192.168.3.2****
root@OpenWrt:/# iperf -s -u -B 224.0.0.1 -p 8080 -i 1
multicast join failed: No such device
------------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on UDP port 8080
Binding to local address 224.0.0.1
Joining multicast group  224.0.0.1
Receiving 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  160 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
multicast join failed: No such device
[  3] local 224.0.0.1 port 8080 connected with 192.168.3.1 port 59175
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth        Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  54.6 KBytes   447 Kbits/sec  24.013 ms   16/   54 (30%)
[  3]  1.0- 2.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  28.932 ms 1260/ 1297 (97%)
[  3]  2.0- 3.0 sec  51.7 KBytes   423 Kbits/sec  28.925 ms 1766/ 1802 (98%)
[  3]  3.0- 4.0 sec  51.7 KBytes   423 Kbits/sec  22.785 ms 1741/ 1777 (98%)
[  3]  4.0- 5.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  27.523 ms 1727/ 1764 (98%)
[  3]  5.0- 6.0 sec  51.7 KBytes   423 Kbits/sec  24.211 ms 1723/ 1759 (98%)
[  3]  6.0- 7.0 sec  57.4 KBytes   470 Kbits/sec  22.281 ms 1876/ 1916 (98%)
[  3]  7.0- 8.0 sec  48.8 KBytes   400 Kbits/sec  28.154 ms 1593/ 1627 (98%)
[  3]  8.0- 9.0 sec  56.0 KBytes   459 Kbits/sec  26.905 ms 1874/ 1913 (98%)
[  3]  9.0-10.0 sec  51.7 KBytes   423 Kbits/sec  27.160 ms 1671/ 1707 (98%)
[  3] 10.0-11.0 sec  51.7 KBytes   423 Kbits/sec  21.963 ms  747/  783 (95%)
[  3] 11.0-12.0 sec  60.3 KBytes   494 Kbits/sec  13.801 ms  631/  673 (94%)
[  3] 12.0-13.0 sec  57.4 KBytes   470 Kbits/sec  15.173 ms  625/  665 (94%)
[  3]  0.0-13.2 sec   711 KBytes   440 Kbits/sec  17.047 ms 17338/17833 (97%)
/*This is send again*/
multicast join failed: No such device
[  4] local 224.0.0.1 port 8080 connected with 192.168.3.1 port 47463
[  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  54.6 KBytes   447 Kbits/sec  24.254 ms   19/   57 (33%)
[  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  50.2 KBytes   412 Kbits/sec  24.307 ms 1237/ 1272 (97%)
[  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  26.490 ms 1715/ 1752 (98%)
[  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  54.6 KBytes   447 Kbits/sec  24.730 ms 1676/ 1714 (98%)
[  4]  4.0- 5.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  22.588 ms 1838/ 1875 (98%)
[  4]  5.0- 6.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  23.496 ms 1786/ 1823 (98%)
[  4]  6.0- 7.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  25.347 ms 1708/ 1745 (98%)
[  4]  7.0- 8.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  24.269 ms 1711/ 1748 (98%)
[  4]  8.0- 9.0 sec  53.1 KBytes   435 Kbits/sec  30.231 ms 1772/ 1809 (98%)
[  4]  9.0-10.0 sec  54.6 KBytes   447 Kbits/sec  24.565 ms 1741/ 1779 (98%)
[  4] 10.0-11.0 sec  54.6 KBytes   447 Kbits/sec  20.195 ms  842/  880 (96%)
[  4] 11.0-12.0 sec  50.2 KBytes   412 Kbits/sec  18.220 ms  547/  582 (94%)
[  4] 12.0-13.0 sec  51.7 KBytes   423 Kbits/sec  18.280 ms  634/  670 (95%)
[  4]  0.0-13.3 sec   701 KBytes   433 Kbits/sec  19.081 ms 17345/17833 (97%)
```

Is wireless UDP multicast restricted by the router? Or where did I not configure it well.
After brushing the two routers, only 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.3.x were modified, and no other modifications were made.

Comment: Please post all output as text in the question itself.  Not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.  Besides, it's much easier to cut and paste the text directly into the question than it is to take a screenshot, upload it to an external site, and create a link to it.

Comment: @ dbush Please help me solve this problem. I haven't slept well in a few days. Work pressure is too great.